# Changing label (wrong reverse) direction using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I use QGIS 3.22.2 and I want to have nice curved labels (along lines): Llyn Brenig Reservoir (currently there are two different labels: Llyn Brenig and Reservoir). Problem is that label Reservoir is displayed in wrong (reverse) direction, as the picture shows.

How I can change reverse direction of label Reservoir to same direction as label Llyn Brenig (as the picture shows)?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

From the **label toolbar** you can **move** and **rotate** labels.

If the label toolbar is not visible it can be activated via:
**View > Toolbars > Label Toolbar**

[image]